# file drag and drop upload in google apps script

Tags: file-upload, google-apps-script, drag-and-drop

I'm trying for days to find how to switch the file upload method in the code below (in google apps script) to drag-and-drop. Is there a way to do that? can someone even give me a code to paste so it will work?

Thanks anyway!

This is the GAS code and the HTML code:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {
  
  try {
    
    var dropbox = "Student Files";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
    
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    
    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);
        
    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();
    
  } catch (error) {
    
    return error.toString();
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name..">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
           onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }
</script>

<style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/). Google Picker API allows you select files and folders from desktop or Google Drive visually by specifying appropriate   view googlepicker.​DocsUploadView or google.picker.​DocsView,respectively. You can use examples on Google Developer page in order to start.

You also need to create or select a project in the Google Developers Console and enable the Google Picker API.

After that you can use Google Picker API via HtmlService in your *form.html* file.

**UPD:** Here is an example with Google Apps Script [code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs).